# How to pass Password to PolarisOffice?

Tags: tizen, tizen-web-app

I tried to open pdf file using Application API, but how can i pass pdf password

```
function openFile() {
    var appControl = new tizen.ApplicationControl("http://tizen.org/appcontrol/operation/view", "file:///opt/usr/media/128.pdf", "application/pdf", null);
    tizen.application.launchAppControl(appControl, "3qwk86ogmg.PolarisOffice",
            function() {
                console.log("launch application control succeed");
            }, function(e) {
                console.log("launch application control failed. reason: "
                        + e.message);
            }, null);
    function onsuccess() {
        console.log("The application has launched successfully");
    }
}
```